# CollectionView does not update anymore after clearing ObservableCollection in ViewModel

Tags: mvvm, view, viewmodel, maui, collectionview

Navigating from MainPage to SecondPage and selecting an item on the list, the properties are loaded on the second grid column just fine. However, when I select another item on the list and clear and repopulate the properties collection, the view isn't updated. What am I missing?

**Model.cs**

```cs
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;

namespace Model;

public class Data : ObservableObject
{
    public string Number {get;set;}

    public string Group {get;set;}

    public string DateTime {get;set;}

    public Data(){}

    public Data(List<object> objList)
    {
        int i=0;
        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in typeof(Data).GetProperties().ToList())
        {           
            property.SetValue(this, objList[i]);
            i++;            
        }
    }   
}

public class PropertiesList : ObservableObject
{
    public string Key {get;set;}

    public string Value {get;set;}

    public PropertiesList(string key, string value)
    {
        Key = key;
        Value = value;  
    }   
}
```

**SecondPage.xaml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="Test.SecondPage"
             xmlns:model="clr-namespace:Model"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Viewmodel"
             xmlns:collections="clr-namespace:CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Collections;assembly=CommunityToolkit.Mvvm"             
             x:DataType="viewmodel:SecondPageViewModel">

  <ContentPage.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Grid">
      <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
        <VisualStateGroupList>
          <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
            <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
            <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
              <VisualState.Setters>
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightGray" />
              </VisualState.Setters>
            </VisualState>
          </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateGroupList>
      </Setter>
    </Style>
  </ContentPage.Resources>

  <Grid Margin="20" RowSpacing="20" RowDefinitions="*,Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*">
    <Grid Grid.Row="0" Margin="20" RowSpacing="20" RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="*,2*">
      <Frame Grid.Column="0" BorderColor="Gray" CornerRadius="10" HasShadow="True">
        <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding ObsDataList}" IsGrouped="True" SelectionMode="Single" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedData, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionChanged="OnDataSelectionChanged">
          <CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="collections:IReadOnlyObservableGroup">
              <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*">
                <Label Text="{Binding Key}" BackgroundColor="LightGray" FontSize="18" FontAttributes="Bold" />
              </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
          </CollectionView.GroupHeaderTemplate>
          <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:Data">
              <Grid Padding="10" RowDefinitions="Auto" ColumnDefinitions="Auto,Auto,Auto,*" ColumnSpacing="50">
                <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Number}" FontSize="20" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                  <VisualStateGroup Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState Name="Selected">
                      <VisualState.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightBlue" />
                      </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                  </VisualStateGroup>
                </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
              </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
          </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
      </Frame>
      <Frame Grid.Column="1" BorderColor="Gray" CornerRadius="10" HasShadow="True">
        <Grid RowDefinitions="*" ColumnDefinitions="*">
          <CollectionView Grid.Column="0" ItemsSource="{Binding ObsDataProperties}" SelectionMode="None">
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
              <DataTemplate x:DataType="model:PropertiesList">
                <Frame BorderColor="Gray" CornerRadius="10">
                  <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto" ColumnDefinitions="200,200" RowSpacing="2">
                    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Key}" FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" FontAttributes="Bold"/>
                    <Label Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Value}" FontSize="10" HorizontalOptions="Start" VerticalOptions="Center" />
                  </Grid>
                </Frame>
              </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
          </CollectionView>
        </Grid>
      </Frame>
    </Grid>
    <Frame Grid.Row="1" BorderColor="Gray" CornerRadius="10" HasShadow="True">
      <Grid RowDefinitions="Auto" ColumnDefinitions="*,*,*" ColumnSpacing="10">
        <Button TextColor="White" FontAutoScalingEnabled="True" Text="Clear" Command="{Binding ClearDataInfoCommand}" HeightRequest="33" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
      </Grid>
    </Frame>
  </Grid>

</ContentPage>
```

**SecondPage.xaml.cs**

```cs
using Model;
using Viewmodel;

namespace Test;

public partial class SecondPage : ContentPage
{
    public SecondPage(SecondPageViewModel viewmodel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewmodel;
    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigatedToEventArgs args)
    {            
        ((SecondPageViewModel)this.BindingContext).GetDataCommand.Execute(null);                

        base.OnNavigatedTo(args);       
    }

    void OnDataSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {        
        if (e.CurrentSelection.Count() != 0) 
            ((SecondPageViewModel)this.BindingContext).ShowDataInfoCommand.Execute(e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Data);            
    }
}
```

**SecondPageViewModel.cs**

```cs
using Model;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Input;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.ComponentModel;
using CommunityToolkit.Mvvm.Collections;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace Viewmodel;

public partial class SecondPageViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private IEnumerable<IGrouping<string, Data>> groupedDataList;

    [ObservableProperty]
    public Data selectedData;

    public ObservableCollection<PropertiesList> ObsDataProperties {get;} = new();

    public ObservableGroupedCollection<string, Data> ObsDataList {get;}  = new();

    public SecondPageViewModel(IServiceProvider provider) : base(provider){} 

    [RelayCommand]
    public async Task GetDataAsync()
    {       
        if (ObsDataList.Count is not 0) ObsDataList.Clear();

        if (ObsDataProperties.Count is not 0) ObsDataProperties.Clear(); 

        await Task.Delay(0);

        List<Data> dataList = new List<Data>()
        {
            new Data
            (
                new List<object>
                {
                    "DATA1",
                    "GROUP1",                    
                    "DATETIME"
                }                               
            ),
            new Data
            (            
                new List<object>
                {
                    "DATA2",
                    "GROUP2",
                    "DATETIME"   
                } 
            )        
        };     

        groupedDataList =  dataList.GroupBy(data => data.Group);  

        foreach(var dataGroup in groupedDataList)
        {            
            ObsDataList.AddGroup(dataGroup);
        }       

    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public void ShowDataInfo(Data data)
    {      
        if (ObsDataProperties.Count is not 0) ObsDataProperties.Clear();       

        foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo property in data.GetType().GetProperties())
        {
            ObsDataProperties.Add
            (
                new PropertiesList
                (
                    property.Name,
                    property.GetValue(data).ToString()
                )        
            );
        }       
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    public void ClearDataInfo()
    {     
        if (ObsDataProperties.Count is not 0) ObsDataProperties.Clear();

        SelectedData = null;
    }
}
```

I expected to see the view updated after selecting another item on the list.

[image: Selecting Data1]

[image: Selecting Data2]

Comment: ShowDataInfo is modifying ObsDataProperties, where GetDataAsync is modifying ObsDataList, so 2 different collections

Comment: Yes they are 2 different collections. ObsDataList is for the left frame and ObsDataProperties appears on the right frame. The problem is with the last one i.e. when i try to repopulate ObsDataProperties nothing appears on the right frame

Comment: When you debug ShowDataInfo, do you receive Data? Are there any exception when the method is run?

Comment: You can recheck if method `ShowDataInfo` has been excuted and recheck if list `ObsDataProperties` has been updated correctly.

Comment: Just debbuged it again. ShowDataInfo is executed and ObsDataProperties is correctly updated with data2 without updating the right frame view. I included images of the run.

Comment: Could you please post a basic demo to github and share the link of it here so that we can test on our side?

Comment: One thing I noticed is that you're using the MVVM Source Generators for the RelayCommands, but you don't use the Source Generators for the properties of your Model and ViewModel classes, although you're inheriting from `ObservableObject`. This is not sufficient when you want to update property values. This may not be the root cause of your issue, but the View will also not be notified when any of the properties of your `Data` instances are updated.